# How to obtain the properties of a CloudObject

Tags: wolfram-cloud

Is there a documented way to obtain the properties of a `CloudObject` like name, path, type, extension without using `CloudObjectInformation`? E.g., the functions `FileType` and `FileByteCount` seem to work for CloudObjects, but other built-in functions like `FileExtension` or `FileDate` do not.

Comment: `FileDate` seems to work now (for $CloudVersion "1.41.1 (April 27, 2017)""1.41.1 (April 27, 2017)" )